# (Express js) How should I use another module in my router? (I keep getting undefined reference error)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pdf.js

I'm making a simple pdf reader application (using the pdf.js library from Mozilla), that the user selects the file and then the website automatically goes to the /reader page, and then it shows the pdf, but I don't know how should I actually transfer that pdf file to my other page, I've tried doing it like this:

This is my server.js

```
import express from 'express';
const app = express();
import router from '../routes/reader.js';
const port = 5500;
const ip = '127.0.0.1';
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use('/css', express.static('css'));
app.use('/node_modules', express.static('node_modules'));
app.use('/js', express.static('js'));
app.use('/docs', express.static('docs'));
app.use('/reader', readerRouter);

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.render('index')
});

app.listen(port, IP);
```

This is where I get the file from the input and send it to the specified URL, this is in a script that I've added to my home page with script tags

```
uploadInput.onchange = (e) => {
  let file = e.target.files[0];
  let fd = new FormData();
  fd.append(uploadInput, file);

  $.ajax({
    url: '/reader',
    method: 'POST',
    data: fd,
    cache: false,
    processData: false,
    contentType: 'application/pdf'
  }).done(() => {
    window.location.href = '/reader';
  });
}
```

And in my /reader router, I did this:

```
const express = require('express');
import showPdf from '../js/pdf.js';
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.render('reader');
});

router.post('/', (req, res) => {
  res.redirect('/reader');
  showPdf(req.body);
});

export default router;
```

I couldn't easily import the pdf.js script, it would throw an error saying that I can't use import outside a module etc... I'm new in node.js and I don't know how these modules work, and how should I import and use them properly, but after doing whatever that I could do to solve the importing issues, now I'm getting an error saying that `pdfjsLib is not defined` in my pdf.js script

This is the pdf.js script:

```
pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = '../node_modules/pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.worker.js';
    
const eventBus = new pdfjsViewer.EventBus();
const pdfLinkService = new pdfjsViewer.PDFLinkService({ eventBus });

// Get document
function showPdf(file) {
  let fileReader = new FileReader();

  fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);

  fileReader.onload = () => {
    let typedArray = new Uint8Array(this.result);
    
    pdfjsLib.getDocument(typedArray).promise.then(function (_pdfDoc) {
      pdfDoc = _pdfDoc;
    });
  }
}
```

it's much larger than this, but it's how I'm using the pdfjsLib and pdfjsViewer, and I'm importing them before my pdf.js script in the HTML script tags.

Why it can't find the pdfjsLib and also the pdfjsViewer? where does the router sit on my website? is this because the router can't access the pdfjsLib global variable? how should I use a script which is dependent on some global variables like this? is this approach correct at all? I mean for transferring the selected file from input and posting it to my other page.

Comment: I don't see where you import `pdfjsLib` and `pdfjsViewer`... You mention "importing them before your HTML script tags" but that would be client-side... you are talking about node.js which is server-side... Something doesn't make sense here yet.

Comment: Where should I import those files? I tried importing them in my pdf.js file, then the errors for pdfjsLib and pdfjsViewer were gone, but some other errors were saying that some other stuff is undefined, which were related to the inner working of these two files, I'll test them again and I'll let you know what the error exactly says

Comment: This is the error: `node_modules\pdfjs-dist\web\pdf_viewer.js:2081
document.webL10n = function (window, document, undefined) {
ReferenceError: document is not defined ... }`

Comment: Then it looks like `pdfjs-dist` is for client-side code. You cannot use it in server-side code. It assumes it runs in a browser.

Comment: Sorry I'm totally a noob in web dev, you mean that I can't make an application like what I described above? and there's no way to grab that file and give it to the pdfjsLib?

Comment: Is it possible if I make a single page application, without node.js and then directly give the input file to the pdfjsLib, and then replace the whole HTML of the home page with the reader page's HTML?

Answer (score 0):

You are exporting a variable called router and then looking for readrouter in your import. Change the import to:

```
import router from '../routes/reader.js
```

For the pdfjsLib I do not see where you are importing that library. So doing the same thing you did for router just import the pdfjsLib library. If you are using [this package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdfjs) its:

```
import pdfjsLib from 'pdfjs-dist'
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, I've changed it multiple times and I forgot to do it this time, unfortunately, it doesn't solve it, I'm still getting `ReferenceError: pdfjsLib is not defined`

Comment: I have updated my answer to try and help.

Comment: No, this pdfjs is from mozilla: https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js

Comment: I've already added them in my html script tags, and they were working fine until I imported my pdf.js script into my router script

Comment: you are importing it on the client side and would need a library to handle it on your server

Comment: Read the comments on the question above as well, and ... what should I exactly do for handling it on the server side?

Comment: Im not sure i really understand what you are trying to accomplish with this. The library works on the client side, so you should be running this script in the browser. Try adding a link to your script on the html page

Comment: Sorry what do you mean by running it in the browser? I want to get the file from the post request and then immediately show the reader page and show the pdf, and which script do you mean that I should add to my page?